# Sublime Text 3 Build System issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have just started playing around with Sublime Text 3 and i am trying to create a build system for python 3.6.3. I have created a **.sublime-build** file with the name **Python3.6.3.sublime-build** which contains the following code :

```
{
"cmd": ["C:/Python32/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"quiet": true
}
```

Whenever I try to build a python file I receive this message at the bottom of the Sublime, in the place where the results from the program should be displayed:

```
[WinError 2] Finding the specified file was not possible by the system
[cmd: ['C:/Python32/python.exe', '-u', 
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\String_examples.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ARM\ADSv1_2\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin]
```

Sorry but the [WinError 2] message was translated in english so it may not be the exact error text.

Moreover when I open sublime I receive this error window:

[Sublime Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Petvi.png)

I am running Windows 7 if that plays any role.

Could someone please explain what did i do wrong because i am kind of stuck with this?
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Are you sure that `C:\Python32\python.exe` is something that actually exists? That error message is the kind you get when Windows can't find the file that you're telling it to run.

Comment: No the path to the python.exe file is not correct. I found out a solution after some hours of research at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of search on the Internet i found that we need to find the right path of the python.exe file and use double backslash instead of single backslash (\) when declaring the file's path. The following answers refer to Windows users.
So the correct code is:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"quiet": true
}
```

If we have the following it will not work:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"quiet": true
}
```

A second way to create the python build system is with this code :

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

In this code notice that the file's path is absent. We only refer the file's name. So Windows will not know where to find the python.exe file and we will have an error message on the Sublime console like the one I describe in my question above. So we need to do the following steps:

1.Go here C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 and copy this path

*Note: Here user is the user name of my computer. It will be different in your case.
(AppData folder maybe hidden check the show hidden files option)*

2. Now right click on Computer icon and click on PROPERTIES's option. Then select ADVANCED SYSTEM settings in left sidebar.
3. Now click on [Environment Variables] and then under [System variables] > [select variable] with name [Path].
4. Click Edit button and then in [Path] value field keep the already existing data and go to end of the line. Type semicolon ( ; ) and don't erase anything just paste the path of Python directory that you copied after the semicolon at the end of the line.

( It should be something like this          ;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32     )

5. Then save the changes and close the Sublime Text. Re-open Sublime and it should be ok.

Notice that the code `"selector": "source.python"`

was not included in the first explation above. Instead there was this code 
     `"quiet": true`
but it does not play any role in the solution of this problem.

After completing the procedure explained second, we have a bonus result. We can use the command **python** on the cmd window without receiving an error because now Windows knows where to find the python.exe file (the path for this file is now included in the PATH parameter of the Windows system).